# Getting facebook place id from instagram place

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, instagram, instagram-api

I know from the documentation of the instagram API that **instagram has facebook locations mapped** so you can search and get the location detail from instagram via facebook place id i.e.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?facebook_places_id=273471170716&access_token=[ACCESS-TOKEN]
```

As you can see I am retreiving the location detail via facebook place id.

But in my scenario, what I want is to get **facebook place id** using instagram id from the instagram location detail. Below is what I mean:

I have got the instagram location id and can get the detail of the place using the following:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/2862169?access_token=[ACCESS-TOKEN]
```

But the above call only returns the location name and geographic co-ordinates. Whereas I want the Facebook place id of the location as well. Is there any way for me to get the facebook place id from the instagram as well?

I **have checked their documentation** on Location endpoints (https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/) and wasn't able to find any relevant information.

The reason why I want that is, I need to get the location detail such as category etc as well which instagram API doesn't provide, so I plan on using this retrieved facebook place id on facebook graph API to retrieve this additional location details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can only use the Facebook Graph API search for this. Therefore, you can use the output from the Instagram API for `latitude`, `longitude` and `name` to construct a Graph API call which returns you a **list** of matching Facebook Place Pages.

If the Instagram location `id` is `788029` for example, the API will return the following JSON:

```
{
    "id": "788029",
    "latitude": 48.858844300000001,
    "longitude": 2.2943506,
    "name": "Eiffel Tower, Paris"
}
```

So, if you take this result and use the data to construct a Facebook Graph API search url, it will result in something like this:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Eiffel%20Tower,%20Paris&type=place&center=48.858844300000001,2.2943506&distance=100&limit=3&access_token={app_access_token}

You can choose the `distance` as well as the `limit` as you desire. If you set `limit=1` you will only receive the place which Facebook deems to be the best match. Replace `{app_access_token}` with an actual App Access Token.

The Facebook response will be something like

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "category": "Local business", 
      "category_list": [
        {
          "id": "276651312419490", 
          "name": "Monument"
        }
      ], 
      "location": {
        "street": "", 
        "city": "Paris", 
        "state": "", 
        "country": "France", 
        "zip": "75007", 
        "latitude": 48.858385562198, 
        "longitude": 2.2944861654879, 
        "located_in": "141184112585566"
      }, 
      "name": "Level 2 Eiffel Tower, Paris", 
      "id": "380503552017025"
    }, 
    {
      "category": "Local business", 
      "category_list": [
        {
          "id": "186825111351005", 
          "name": "Tourist Attraction"
        }
      ], 
      "location": {
        "street": "", 
        "city": "Paris", 
        "state": "", 
        "country": "France", 
        "zip": "", 
        "latitude": 48.858205346341, 
        "longitude": 2.2944900587791
      }, 
      "name": "Eiffel Tower Sommett, Paris, France", 
      "id": "1458706024363987"
    }, 
    {
      "category": "Restaurant/cafe", 
      "category_list": [
        {
          "id": "168976549819329", 
          "name": "French Restaurant"
        }
      ], 
      "location": {
        "street": "", 
        "city": "Paris", 
        "state": "", 
        "country": "France", 
        "zip": "75007", 
        "latitude": 48.858532957713, 
        "longitude": 2.2941094631632, 
        "located_in": "141184112585566"
      }, 
      "name": "58 Tour Eiffel (officiel)", 
      "id": "148894855169991"
    }
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/search?limit=3&type=place&q=Eiffel Tower, Paris&center=48.858844300000001,2.2943506&distance=100&offset=3&__after_id=enc_AdCYS3bVKOc29JFMrqlsouSZCvBxUTYZC7nHvqDHKAiBNrOs2ehUIaOsJ2wL9TxF9KOfgGmqEPOaLwotDM4pIUqyFf"
  }
}
```

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.2#search
- https://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/locations/